# UnicodeDecodeError when appending pandas dataframe to Microsoft SQL table using Pandas

Tags: sql-server, python-2.7, pandas, sqlalchemy

I am using python 2 to append dataframe to a Microsoft SQL table using Pandas to_sql function. The funny thing is when I run my code in environment A, which writes the dataframe to Table A, it can write successfully. But when I run my code in environment B which write the dataframe to Table B, it will crash with the following error message.

Both environment has the same python libraries and same version. Both table A and B have the same encoding and schema. Both environment has the same setup.

I am perplexed by this bug. Do you have any suggestion why this happens? Thank you.

The code

```
df.to_sql(name=tbl_name, con=con, if_exists='append', index=False)
```

The error message

```
File "D:\Anaconda2\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\generic.py", line 1345, in to_sql
chunksize=chunksize, dtype=dtype)
File "D:\Anaconda2\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\sql.py", line 471, in to_sql
chunksize=chunksize, dtype=dtype)
File "D:\Anaconda2\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\sql.py", line 1151, in to_sql
table.insert(chunksize)
File "D:\Anaconda2\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\sql.py", line 666, in insert
self._execute_insert(conn, keys, chunk_iter)
File "D:\Anaconda2\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\sql.py", line 641, in _execute_insert
conn.execute(self.insert_statement(), data)
File "D:\Anaconda2\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\engine\base.py", line 945, in execute
return meth(self, multiparams, params)
File "D:\Anaconda2\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\sql\elements.py", line 263, in _execute_on_connection
return connection._execute_clauseelement(self, multiparams, params)
File "D:\Anaconda2\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\engine\base.py", line 1053, in _execute_clauseelement
compiled_sql, distilled_params
File "D:\Anaconda2\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\engine\base.py", line 1189, in _execute_context
context)
File "D:\Anaconda2\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\engine\base.py", line 1405, in _handle_dbapi_exception
util.reraise(*exc_info)
File "D:\Anaconda2\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\engine\base.py", line 1159, in _execute_context
context)
File "D:\Anaconda2\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\engine\default.py", line 467, in do_executemany
cursor.executemany(statement, parameters)
UnicodeDecodeError: 'ascii' codec can't decode byte 0xc3 in position 7: ordinal not in range(128)
```

Comment: I'm guessing yes but the starting data in the 2 tables is exactly the same (you did state the schema was)?

Comment: No, the starting data in the 2 tables is different, but the schema is the same